# simple_html_dom html parser not returning correct result

Tags: php, html-parsing

I am trying to list all the hostels in my city from booking.com . I am using simple_html_dom parser class. Below is my code.

```
 require_once("simple_html_dom.php");  

 //booking.com url

 $url='https://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?
 aid=304142&label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaBGIAQGYAS7CAQp3aW5kb3dzIDEwyAEM2AED6AEBkgIBeagCAw&sid=33271cc22ad69fa488b3e664c93ba447&class_interval=1&dest_id=-2705195&dest_type=city&from_sf=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA&rows=15&sb_price_type=total&search_selected=1&src=index&ss=Baku%2C%20Azerbaijan&ss_raw=baku&ssb=empty&nflt=ht_id%3D203%3B&lsf=ht_id%7C203%7C35&unchecked_filter=hoteltype';

 $html = file_get_html($url);
 echo $html;`
```

When I run this code on my local machine I receive **54 hostels(but should have received 35)**:[image]

And this is what I get when I paste the url in browser:[image]

*So my question is, why I get different result from the same link?*

Comment: I get 54 in the browser.

Comment: The dates are different in the two screenshots. The first one is for 1 Nov through 14 Nov, the second is for 4 Nov through 19 Nov.

Comment: Your search results may be influenced by browser cookies

Comment: @Barmar, but I havent specified any date in search.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I think so too

Comment: Something is causing you to get different dates when you put the URL into the browser. Probably cookies, as mentioned above.

Comment: @Barmar  got it. Thanks